# Probabilistic Constraint

Tags: probability

Can anyone please tell me if the following two statements are equivalent for all distributions of x and if so then how?

$$\Pr \{ \;x \geq 0\;\} \leq \;p $$
$$\Pr \{ \;x \leq 0\;\} \geq \;1-p $$

Comment: They are only equivalent if $\Pr(X=0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the R.v. $X\equiv0$ then $Pr(X\geq 0)=Pr(X\leq 0)= Pr(X = 0) =1$

Comment: But assuming a continuous random variable, ...

Comment: @almagest: The question doesn't assume a continuous random variable, so the counterexample is fine. If the variable is [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition), then $\Pr(X=0)=0$ and the two statements are equivalent.